# How do I update a value in one cell of a column based on a test of two different table's columns? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, windows, csv

I have two tables, `TableA` and `TableB`.

- `TableA` has a column named `pointId`
- `TableB` has a column named `alarmId`

I need to query the first table's column `pointID` and check to see if it equals the second table's column name `alarmID`.

(This is the basic idea of what I'm trying to do... I haven't found the proper syntax for it though, so this is not working code)

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET TableA.pointID = 'new value'
WHERE TableA.pointID = TableB.alarmId
```

So, basically, I want to set a new value for `pointId` where I find that `pointID` and `alarmID` are equal to each other.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE TableA SET TableA.pointID = 'new value'  from TableA Join TableB ON TableA.pointID = TableB.alarmId
WHERE....
```

You will need other filter conditions (in where condition) because the code above will set all the values of pointID to 'new value' wherever TableA.pointID = TableB.alarmId

Hope it solves the issue.

Comment: That’s it! Thank you for your help!